# SQL - Count rows based on 2 restrictions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have an `employees` table with a `hire_date` column and the query I'm trying to make is to count how many employees were hired in 1995 and 1996. Where 1995 has its own column and 1996 has its own column:

```
 ______________
|      |      |
| 1995 | 1996 | 
|______|______|
|   2  |   3  | 
|______|______|`
```

Pseudocode:

```
display COUNT of rows WHERE hire_date LIKE '%95', display COUNT of rows WHERE hire_date LIKE '%96'
```

Could anyone guide me as to how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this query you only access once to employees table

```
select  
  sum(case TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'YYYY') when '1995' then 1 end) as "1995",
  sum(case TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'YYYY') when '1996' then 1 end) as "1996"
  from employees
 where hire_date between date '1995-01-01' and date'1996-12-31';
```

Comment: I like this method but TO_CHAR conversions would need to be done on `hire_date` for comparisons: `TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'YYYY')`

Comment: @Ethan I updated the answer in case Hire_date is a Date.

Comment: Note that `date'1996-12-31'` evaluates to 0:00am so does not include the rest of that last day - so this code assumes `hire_date` is always set to 0:00am for those lucky people who get hired on 31 December.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Yes, you are right. I assumed that hire_date was just a date. If not you can use:
hire_date >= date '1995-01-01' and 
hire_date  < date'1997-01-01'. I was trying to make the where condition Sargable

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees WHERE hire_date = '1995') "1995",
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees WHERE hire_date = '1996') "1996"
FROM dual;
```